# Is there any way to send if else statement to remote server while using expect command in shell script?

Tags: bash, ssh, expect

I want to connect a remote server via ssh using expect and check specific directory exists if not create file if exists create subsequent directory. I can connect remote server and send line commands but when it comes to statement like if else it doesn't accept.

Here is my code snippet. It only connects remote and exits.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 120
spawn ssh user@remoteIP
expect "*?assword:"
send "remote password"
expect "$ "
set name "b"
send "if [ -d /path/to/remote/directory/$name ]; then
    set i 1
  while [ -d /path/to/remote/directory/$name$i ]; do
      let i++
    done
   set name $name$i
  fi"
send -- "mkdir -p /path/to/remote/directory/$name\r"
expect "$ "
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but you really should explain in more detail what your code should do, what exactly isn't working, and what you have done to troubleshoot it. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you send to the shell needs to be valid shell script. You can't expect the shell to update your Expect variables, or vice versa.

Try the following:

```
send "i=''
while \[ -d /path/to/remote/directory/$name\$i ]; do
   let i++
done
mkdir -p /path/to/remote/directory/$name\$i\r"
```

The variable `$name` is your Expect variable, while `\$i` should be passed through to the shell as literally `$i`. Similarly, `[` needs to be escaped to avoid executing it as an Expect construct.

For completeness, here is the full script with this change.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout 120
spawn ssh user@remoteIP
expect "*?assword:"
send "remote password"
expect "$ "
set name "b"
send "i=''
while \[ -d /path/to/remote/directory/$name\$i ]; do
   let i++
done
mkdir -p /path/to/remote/directory/$name\$i\r"
expect "$ "
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
```

Comment: `let i++` is obsolescent, but I suppose it's elegant and succinct if you are sure the remote shell is Bash.